# bash finding most recent date between two strings

Tags: string, bash, date

I have two directories where the files are setup as yyyymmdd.hhmmss format. For example:

```
 dir1:
 20190101.020000
 20190101.021000
 20190101.022000
 ....

 dir2:
 20190101.015135
 20190101.015922
 20190101.020159
 20190101.020707
 20190101.021404
 20190101.022000
 ....
```

I want the dates that are in dir1 to be the *most recent after* the date that is in dir2 (or if they match exactly, then that time is selected). The matching would be:

```
20190101.020000 and 20190101.015922
20190101.021000 and 20190101.020707
20190101.022000 and 20190101.022000
```

given the above examples. I know that strings can be converted to dates in bash with 'date -d', but what would be an efficient way to carry out the task at hand?

Comment: Use floating point arithmetic and substract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may look tricky but will work:

```
while IFS="/" read -r dir file; do
    [[ $dir = "dir2" ]] && prev2="$file"
    [[ $dir = "dir1" ]] && echo "$file and $prev2"
done < <(find dir1 dir2 -type f | sort -t "/" -k2 -k1.1r)
```

Result:

```
20190101.020000 and 20190101.015922
20190101.021000 and 20190101.020707
20190101.022000 and 20190101.022000
```

- It first sorts all pathnames with filename as 1st key and dirname as
  second key.
- Then it scans the sorted list from the top to the bottom by picking the nearest
  filename in dir2 whenever hitting a file in dir1.

Comment: Why do you need the `find ... sort ` logic ? Simple ls dir1/* dir2/* should work ?

Comment: @dash-o [Why *not* parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: the articles (and issues related to parsing is output) is  about trying to parse information from `ls -l`. Also there are many issue with handling file names with special characters. It has nothing to do with plain `ls` used to get list of files. On a technical note, `echo dir1/* dir2/*` will be even more efficient vs `ls ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The ASK is for each file1 in `dir1` to find the lowest file in `dir2` that is >= file1. The brute force way to iterate over the two arrays. Since the srings are comparable, no need to convert to dates.

```
#! /bin/bash

readarray -t l1 < <(cd dir1 ; ls -1)
readarray -t l2 < <(cd dir2 ; ls -1)

for file1 in "${l1[@]}" ; do
    prev2=
    for file2 in "${l2[@]}" ; do
        if [[ "$file1" < "$file2" ]] ; then
            break
        fi
        prev2=$file2
    done
    echo "$file1 $prev2"
done
```

If the list are very large, might make sense to run a 'merge' between the two. But this will require large number of items (>1000 ?) to make a difference.